# Wait for all jobs of a user to finish before submitting subsequent jobs to a PBS cluster

Tags: shell, cluster-computing, wait, pbs, qsub

I am trying to adjust some bash scripts to make them run on a ([pbs](/questions/tagged/pbs)) cluster.

The individual tasks are performed by several script thats are started by a main script.
So far this main scripts starts multiple scripts in background (by appending `&`) making them run in parallel on one multi core machine.
I want to substitute these calls by `qsub`s to distribute load accross the cluster nodes.

However, some jobs depend on others to be finished before they can start.
So far, this was achieved by `wait` statements in the main script.
But what is the best way to do this using the grid engine?

I already found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11525214/wait-for-set-of-qsub-jobs-to-complete) as well as the `-W after:jobid[:jobid...]` documentation in the `qsub` man page but I hope there is a better way.
We are talking about several thousend jobs to run in parallel first and another set of the same size to run simultatiously after the last one of these finished.
This would mean I had to queue a lot of jobs depending on a lot of jobs.

I could bring this down by using a dummy job in between, doing nothing but depending on the first group of jobs, on which the second group could depend.
This would decrease the number of dependencies from millions to thousands but still: It feeles wrong and I am not even sure if such a long command line would be accepted by the shell.

- Isn't there a way to wait for all *my* jobs to finish (something like `qwait -u <user>`)?
- Or all jobs that where submitted from *this* script (something like `qwait [-p <PID>]`)?

Of course it would be possible to write something like this using `qstat` and `sleep` in a `while` loop, but I guess this use case is important enough to have a built in solution and I was just incapable to figure that one out.

**What would you recommend / use in such a situation?**

**Addendum I:**

Since it was requested in a comment:

```
$ qsub --version
version: 2.4.8
```

Maybe also helpful to determine the exact [pbs](/questions/tagged/pbs) system:

```
$ qsub --help
usage: qsub [-a date_time] [-A account_string] [-b secs]
      [-c [ none | { enabled | periodic | shutdown |
      depth=<int> | dir=<path> | interval=<minutes>}... ]
      [-C directive_prefix] [-d path] [-D path]
      [-e path] [-h] [-I] [-j oe] [-k {oe}] [-l resource_list] [-m n|{abe}]
      [-M user_list] [-N jobname] [-o path] [-p priority] [-P proxy_user] [-q queue]
      [-r y|n] [-S path] [-t number_to_submit] [-T type] [-u user_list] [-w] path
      [-W otherattributes=value...] [-v variable_list] [-V] [-x] [-X] [-z] [script]
```

Since the comments point to job arrays so far I searched the `qsub` man page with the following results:

```
[...]
DESCRIPTION
[...]
       In addition to the above, the following environment variables will be available to the batch job.
[...]
       PBS_ARRAYID
              each member of a job array is assigned a unique identifier (see -t)
[...]
OPTIONS
[...]
       -t array_request
               Specifies the task ids of a job array. Single task arrays are allowed.
               The array_request argument is an integer id or a range of integers. Multiple ids or id ranges can be combined in a comman delimeted list. Examples : -t 1-100 or -t 1,10,50-100
[...]
```

**Addendum II:**

I have tried the [torque](/questions/tagged/torque) solution given by Dmitri Chubarov but it does not work as described.

Without the job arrray it works as expected:

```
testuser@headnode ~ $ qsub -W depend=afterok:`qsub ./test1.sh` ./test2 && qstat
2553.testserver.domain
Job id                  Name             User            Time Use S Queue
----------------------- ---------------- --------------- -------- - -----
2552.testserver         Test1            testuser               0 Q testqueue
2553.testserver         Test2            testuser               0 H testqueue
testuser@headnode ~ $ qstat
Job id                  Name             User            Time Use S Queue
----------------------- ---------------- --------------- -------- - -----
2552.testserver         Test1            testuser               0 R testqueue
2553.testserver         Test2            testuser               0 H testqueue
testuser@headnode ~ $ qstat
Job id                  Name             User            Time Use S Queue
----------------------- ---------------- --------------- -------- - -----
2553.testserver         Test2            testuser               0 R testqueue
```

However, using job arrays the second job won't start:

```
testuser@headnode ~ $ qsub -W depend=afterok:`qsub -t 1-2 ./test1.sh` ./test2 && qstat
2555.testserver.domain
Job id                  Name             User            Time Use S Queue
----------------------- ---------------- --------------- -------- - -----
2554-1.testserver       Test1-1          testuser               0 Q testqueue
2554-2.testserver       Test1-1          testuser               0 Q testqueue
2555.testserver         Test2            testuser               0 H testqueue
testuser@headnode ~ $ qstat
Job id                  Name             User            Time Use S Queue
----------------------- ---------------- --------------- -------- - -----
2554-1.testserver       Test1-1          testuser               0 R testqueue
2554-2.testserver       Test1-2          testuser               0 R testqueue
2555.testserver         Test2            testuser               0 H testqueue
testuser@headnode ~ $ qstat
Job id                  Name             User            Time Use S Queue
----------------------- ---------------- --------------- -------- - -----
2555.testserver         Test2            testuser               0 H testqueue
```

I guess this is due to the lack of array indication in the job id that is returned by the first `qsub`:

```
testuser@headnode ~ $ qsub -t 1-2 ./test1.sh
2556.testserver.domain
```

As you can see there is no `...[]` indicating this being a job array.
Also, in the `qsub` output there are no `...[]`s but `...-1` and `...-2` indicating the array.

So the remaining question is how to format `-W depend=afterok:...` to make a job depend on a specified job array.

Comment: There are a few PBS-derived queueing systems out there; do you know exactly what you're using? Some have features like "job arrays" - a series of independently running jobs which can be treated as a single entity for the purposes of dependencies (or cancelling, or..)

Comment: @JonathanDursi: Unfortunately I do not know the exact system. Is there a way to figure it out? `--version` reports nothing but a version number and the man page doesn't seem to contain any details, either. If there is no way to find out on myself I could email the administrator of the cluster as a last resort.

Comment: @DmitriChubarov: I added the output of `--version` and `--help`. Hopefully that does any good.

Comment: @JonathanDursi: I added the job array related parts of the qsub man page. Does this help you answering the question?

Comment: I think you're using Torque 2.4.8; somewhat old but it has some initial support for job arrays.  @DimitriChubarov's answer below will get you on the right path.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Filling in following the solution suggested by Jonathan in the comments.

There are several resource managers based on the original Portable Batch System: OpenPBS, TORQUE and PBS Professional. The systems had diverged significantly and use different command syntax for newer features such as job arrays.

Job arrays are a convenient way to submit multiple similar jobs based on the same job script. Quoting from the manual:

> Sometimes users will want to submit large numbers of jobs based on the
>   same job script. Rather than using a script to repeatedly call **qsub**, a
>   feature known as job arrays now exists to allow the creation of
>   multiple jobs with one **qsub** command.

To submit a job array PBS provides the following syntax:

```
 qsub -t 0-10,13,15 script.sh
```

this submits jobs with ids from 0,1,2,...,10,13,15.

Within the script the variable `PBS_ARRAYID` carries the id of the job within the array and can be used to pick the necessary configuration.

Job array have their specific dependency options.

#### TORQUE

TORQUE resource manager that is probably used in the OP. There additional dependency options are provided that can be seen in the following example:

```
$ qsub -t 1-1000 script.sh
1234[].pbsserver.domainname
$ qsub -t 1001-2000 -W depend=afterokarray:1234[] script.sh
1235[].pbsserver.domainname
```

This will result in the following `qstat` output

```
1234[]         script.sh    user          0 R queue
1235[]         script.sh    user          0 H queue
```

Tested on torque version 3.0.4

The full afterokarray syntax is in the `qsub(1)` manual.

#### PBS Professional

In PBS Professional dependencies can work uniformly on ordinary jobs and array jobs. Here is an example:

```
$ qsub -J 1-1000 -ry script.sh
1234[].pbsserver.domainname
$ qsub -J 1001-2000 -ry -W depend=afterok:1234[] script.sh
1235[].pbsserver.domainname
```

This will result in the following `qstat` output

```
1234[]         script.sh    user          0 B queue
1235[]         script.sh    user          0 H queue
```

#### Update on Torque versions

Array dependencies became available in Torque since version 2.5.3. Job arrays from version 2.5 are not compatible with job arrays in versions 2.3 or 2.4. In particular the `[]` syntax was introduced in Torque since version 2.5.

#### Update on using a delimeter job

For torque versions prior to 2.5 a different solution may work that is based on submitting dummy delimeter jobs between batches of jobs to be separated. 
It uses three dependency types: `on`,`before`, and `after`.

Consider the following example

```
 $ DELIM=`qsub -Wdepend=on:1000 dummy.sh `
 $ qsub -Wdepend=beforeany:$DELIM script.sh
 1001.pbsserver.domainname
 ... another 998 jobs ...
 $ qsub -Wdepend=beforeany:$DELIM script.sh
 2000.pbsserver.domainname
 $ qsub -Wdepend=after:$DELIM script.sh
 2001.pbsserver.domainname
 ...
```

This will result in the queue state like this

```
1000         dummy.sh    user          0 H queue
1001         script.sh   user          0 R queue   
...
2000         script.sh   user          0 R queue   
2001         script.sh   user          0 H queue
...
```

That is the job #2001 will run only after the previous 1000 jobs terminate. Probably the rudimentary job array facilities available in TORQUE 2.4 can be used as well to submit the script job.

This solution will also work for TORQUE version 2.5 and higher.

Comment: Corrected a syntax error in the `torque` example. The array job id in the `afterokarray` clause should have an array suffix `[]`.

Comment: Even with the corrected syntax this doesn't work for me. I updated the question with the results of the corresponding test.

Comment: @sg-lecram sorry this `afterokarray` feature is present in Torque 2.5.8, but is not yet available in Torque 2.4.8.

Comment: Thank you for your help so far. +1 for that. But is there another way to achieve this without updating the PBS system? Maybe by submitting the second array later and waiting for all jobs the corresponding user in the submit-script (as suggested by my `qwait` examples)?

Comment: @sg-lecram I think I found a reasonable compromise that should work for Torque versions prior 2.5. Please check it out.