# Torque job with dependencies on job array

Tags: cluster-computing, batch-processing, pbs, qsub, torque

I'm trying to submit a torque job that is dependent on an array completing.

`` FIRST=`qsub -q hep -t 1-5 foo.sh` ``
`qsub -q hep -W depend=afterok:$FIRST bar.sh`

The FIRST job array submits and completes just fine but the second job bar.sh just holds indefinitely.

If I remove the array option from the first argument the second job will succeed as planned but this does not really solve the problem.

There was a similar thread from 3 years ago but it seems that there was no actual resolution: 
[How to wait for a torque job array to complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19517923/how-to-wait-for-a-torque-job-array-to-complete)

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 7):

Found the answer, the depend argument must be `afterokarray`. The example below works.

`` FIRST=`qsub -q hep -t 1-5 foo.sh` ``
`qsub -q hep -W depend=afterokarray:$FIRST bar.sh`