# Wait for set of qsub jobs to complete before next command

Tags: bash, pbs

Since the resource limit in the cluster I use, I submitted a bunch of jobs by using for loop in bash. I want to wait for all the jobs in pbs to complete before next command. The link here seems to solve my problem [Wait for set of qsub jobs to complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11525214/wait-for-set-of-qsub-jobs-to-complete)
but I am still confused what I should put after -cwd if I don't have next job script to run but some simple bash commands

Here is for loop to submit pbs task

```
for i in `seq 1 10`; do
if [ "$i"==10 ]; then
    EndLine=$((SeqNum*2))
fi
EndLine=$((StartLine-1+(EachFile+1)*2));
NewFile='StHeBC2-'$i'.fasta'
sed -n "$StartLine,$EndLine p" StHeBC2.fasta > $NewFile
StartLine=$((EndLine+1))
JobFile='StHeBC2-'$i'.sh'

    echo "
    #!/bin/bash
    #PBS -l ncpus=8
    #PBS -l mem=8GB
    #PBS -l nodes=4
    #PBS -l walltime=120:00:00
    #PBS -m bea
    #PBS -W umask=33

    cd $PBS_O_WORKDIR
    TransDecoder -t $NewFile -m 15 --search_pfam Pfam-A.hmm --API --CPU 8
    " > $JobFile

    qsub $JobFile
done
```

I want to summarize the output of TransDecoder using some basic command cat/cut etc after all JobFiles are done in pbs, like

```
cat test-*.fasta.transdecoder.pep > test.fasta.transdecoder.pep
```

Anyone can help? Thank you

Comment: which version of pbs are you using? What does `qsub --version` return?

Comment: In TORQUE you can use job dependencies to accomplish this. I'd assume that PBSPro offers a similar feature.