# Sun Grid Engine - Script launching an Array-jobs and waiting for all of them to finish

Tags: bash, parallel-processing, cluster-computing, sungridengine

When you submit an arrayjob, you do something like this:

```
qsub -t 1-1000 -N myArray arrayjob.sh 
#This execute arrayjob 1000 simultaneus times, calling the job "myArray"
```

I would like to wrap this in another script that tells me "Ehi, all the tasks are done!"

Some people will propose:

```
qsub somethingAfterAllTheTask.sh -hold_jid "myArray"
```

But

- I don't want to start another job to execute after myArray: I want to resume the script from which I executed the qsub of myArray
- myArray is gonna die after launching all the tasks, not after all those tasks are done: I have to wait for the tasks' completion, not for myArray's

So what I want is a pseudo-script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
qsub -t 1-1000 -N myArray arrayjob.sh
if [all_the_task_are_completed]; then
    echo Done!
fi
```

How do I obtain such behavior? Thanks in advance

There is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11525214/wait-for-set-of-qsub-jobs-to-complete) but it's not about array-jobs, and it still does not satisfy my problem

Comment: `-sync y` should do the trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `-sync y` when submitting the arrayjob, the command which launches all the tasks will not die until all the tasks are finished.

Thanks to @Oo.oO for the tip